# Where to choose to rebuild after a population reducing event?

Tags: science-based, society, post-apocalypse, geography

I am trying to come up with a cohesive and easy to understand set of rules for finding where to "start over".

The setting is a group of hikers come out to a world that has collapsed for an unknown reason. >99% of all human life has ended and there is zero explanation. However, in this world all resources are now available, anything and everything is free, all land is believed to be unowned now...basically the world is your oyster, and you are free to rebuild anywhere.

A few rules.

The characters will use the rail systems to travel, cheaper and easier to use converted rail vehicles (motor vehicles with the rail attachments, so a car can travel on the tracks). With so little human life left, there aren't border or land wars, so people are not a catalyst for large conflicts. The group would be looking for mild climate, good soil, access to the sea but not within danger of large storms, near a rail hub or within 100 miles, no man-made dangers i.e., nuclear reactors, dams, zoos. Keep in mind that the rail lines will be used to transport needed items from other areas, so their area of reach will most likely be less than 1000 miles by rail.  Basically, I am looking for as close to utopia as possible and looking for a set of possible locations and why they would be the best.

Comment: Google search "worlds cleanest rivers" and choose from the list. Abundant, clean water is going to be essential to your survival. Plenty more things to consider, but I would start there

Comment: How big is this group of hikers? The number of people to do such things as run a railroad is quite large. Ironically, a rail line is pretty delicate and requires a lot of care and feeding. Compare it to a paved highway that will degrade quite gradually, and still be travelable.  Replacing a broken rail is a huge task.

Comment: Where are you starting?  If you are on the Isle of Man that simplifies things considerably.

Comment: Hello Broke. I try not to vote to close new user questions, but I need to vote to close this one. Where to rebuild has so many variables, some of which are purely aesthetic while others might be practical, that it's impossible to give you an objective answer. I like forests. Others like valleys. Others like the ocean. Some like Elk. Others like Trout. Others like Oysters. You can grow things almost anywhere. Mines exist all over the place. Any answer you receive here is of no more value than putting a world map on the wall and letting a chimp throw a dart at it. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Now, if you [edit] your question to give us a list of specific expectations, limitations, conditions, and constraints, then this *might* (maybe) become an on-topic question. But at this time, all answers are of equal value, which is prohibited. (Everybody will have their preferences along with seemingly rational explanations for why, but no rationalization is any better than another based on your question). We discourage brainstorming. It's worth your time to carefully read the [tour] and the following two pages: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask].

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with JBH entirely, but most of that is pretty accurate to say. However, even without drilling it down a bit more, there are plenty of geographical interests and obstacles near major, clean rivers that would contribute to the complexities of your story. Like canyons, mountain ranges, bodies of salt water, etc. So on top of having to deal with rail ways and such, you can narrow the requirements by imagining what complexities a bridge going over a canyon would bring to your story and whether or not you want to address these things in your story. Or any other feature.

Comment: start by narrowing it down to a continent, next how many people , and how soon after the event is it? these are important because we need to know how many mouths to feed, how much upkeep can they do, how much have things degraded. also as others have said rationalizing your criteria can be important, for instance a zoo is a area full of dead exotic animals without humans. its not really a hazard, ditto for most nuclear powerplants in the developed world.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Any major city  established before 1900 will do

There's a reason that the world's cities are where they are - they have everything needed for many people to live there - fresh water, arable land, and good water transport. There are a few exceptions for cities established after 1900 because the technology could overcome, for example, the problems of desert cities like Dubai or Las Vegas.

For a small group of hikers, an empty city will have everything they need:

- Rail connections are built-in
- Green space can easily be farmed
- There will be a source of freshwater - this may be a fair distance from the city, but the pipes and aqueducts should keep working for a long time in most areas. Municipal water supplies rely on gravity rather than pumps wherever they can.
- Similarly, if they pick the right part of the city, sewerage pipes can carry away their waste. Sure, it won't be treated before discharge, but that will be many km from the base of operations.
- The city will be a virtually endless source of manufactured goods and preserved foodstuffs.
- It shouldn't be too hard to find a generator. Preferably a diesel one because petrol will go bad after a few months. Hook that up to a service station, and the diesel in the underground tank will keep it going for a long time. Of course, when that one dries up, you move on to the next.
- Shelter. Take your pick of any of the buildings.